SSRS Configuration Manager extremely slow - 45-60s of "Attempt to reconnect to RPC server failed with hr = 0x800706b3" after each action
I have been trying to configure SSRS to use SSL. I did this successfully on one server but doing the exact same actions on another server was not working. One key thing I noticed is it would only bind IPv6 to 443 but not IPv4. If I added IPv4 it would not there when I loaded the binding window again. Also there were root certificates and a self signed server cert in the SSL cert select drop down. I found there were root certs in the Personal cert store...
After removing the self signed cert and the root level certs from the Personal certificate store now SSRS can be configured exactly as expected but somewhere along the way it has slowed to a crawl. Looking at logs every action is followed by up to 60 seconds of:
Attempt to reconnect to RPC server failed with hr = 0x800706b3
before then continuing on with the change.
So modifying configurations is very slow and the SSRS reports time out when trying to load via browser. This appears to be only due to that error as there are no issues with load on the server.
